# How to create a background over non-sibling DOM nodes?

Tags: html, css

So I have a web page nicely organized as such:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <header>header</header>
    <main style="max-width: 80vw; margin: 0 auto;">
      <section>section 1</section>
      <section>section 2</section>
      <section>section 3</section>
      <section>section 4</section>
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have a background with linear-gradient spanning the header and the first section.
It raises two issues:

- how to create an element that spans non-sibling DOM nodes?
- how to create an element that spans over the limited width of the first section?

Ideally I would like to keep my HTML organization, because it is semantic.

[image: Edit infallible-silence-wcjkr]

Comment: Are the heights of the elements constant? (In this case `30vh`, or in the case of media queries any other constant value)

Comment: @Louis Coulet: I came up with one solution for your problem. I also enjoyed working on it. If my answer helps you do accept it and vote for it for other developers to get help from. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to create an element that spans non-sibling DOM nodes?

You can't. Valid HTML requires a hierarchy with only one direct parent (in your hypothetical example the first `section` would have two: `main` and the new one with a gradient).

If you wish to achieve this effect you have several options:

### Alter your hierarchy

You could flatten your hierarchy into

```
<div class="gradient-wrapper">
  <header>header</header>
  <section>section 1</section>
</div>
<section>section 2</section>
<section>section 3</section>
<section>section 4</section>
```

and impose the original style of `main` onto the sections using

```
section {
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gradient-wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(...);
}
```

This is the easiest method as it is vertically responsive by design: the gradient will automatically stretch to encompass its children.

[image: Edit zealous-sound-7jvy4]

### Constant height using CSS

If the height of, and distance to your first `section` are known and constant, you can deploy a CSS hack to make the background of your `header` stick out to exactly the height of your `section` (without changing the original hierarchy).

```
header {
  position: relative;
}

header::before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

  --first-section-height: (1px + 30vh + 2px);
  height: calc(100% + var(--first-section-height));

  background: linear-gradient(...);
}
```

For clarity I have created the `--first-section-height` variable which represents the total height from the bottom of your `header` to the bottom of your `section`.

*`1px` is the `border-bottom` of `header`,

`30vh` is the constant height of your `section` and

`2px` is its `border-top` and `border-bottom`.*

[image: Edit vibrant-liskov-uw2zh]

### Javascript

If you wish to keep your original hierarchy and need your `section` to be variable sized or spaced, you could resort to javascript to listen for changes in the window size and position a `div` at the combined bounding boxes of the two elements. A minimal working example of that behaviour:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", updateGradientBox);
window.addEventListener("resize", updateGradientBox);
updateGradientBox();

function updateGradientBox() {
  let header = document.querySelector("header");
  let section = document.querySelector("main section:first-child");
  let gradient = document.querySelector("#gradient");
  if (header === null || section === null || gradient === null) return;

  let rects = [header, section].map((el) => el.getBoundingClientRect());
  let rect = getCombinedBoundingRect(rects);

  gradient.style.top = `${rect.top}px`;
  gradient.style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
  gradient.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
  gradient.style.height = `${rect.height}px`;
}

function getCombinedBoundingRect(rects) {
  const r = {
    top: Math.min(...rects.map((r) => r.top)),
    left: Math.min(...rects.map((r) => r.left)),
    bottom: Math.max(...rects.map((r) => r.bottom)),
    right: Math.max(...rects.map((r) => r.right))
  };
  return {
    ...r,
    width: r.right - r.left,
    height: r.bottom - r.top
  };
}
```

```css
#gradient {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(217, 217, 217, 1) 0%, rgba(85, 85, 85, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="gradient"></div>
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <section>section 1</section>
  <section>section 2</section>
  <section>section 3</section>
  <section>section 4</section>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

The advantage of this method is that it adapts to every thinkable size and position (as witnessed by my minimal example not at all representing your proposed layout).
A full working example can be found on

[image: Edit naughty-fermi-0i2l5]

*(Please keep in mind that I'm using the latest javascript syntax and API in my example; depending on your desired support for older browsers you may want to polyfill or compile it using Babel)*

Comment: Thank you, your 3 solutions work, you explain clearly the different approaches. Now all 3 have drawbacks: first one messes up the semantic hierarchy, second one needs CSS-computable heights, third one introduces javascript for styling. I like your getCombinedBoundingRect function!

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with this solution using javascript. Hope I have understood the problem in correct way :)

Main idea is to get exact heights of the `header` and the first `section` dynamically and set gradient on body upto that height.

**Codepen:** https://codesandbox.io/s/the-gradient-stuff-h3yx1

```js
const header = document.querySelector("header");
const section1 = document.querySelector("main section:first-child");

const headerHeight = header.getBoundingClientRect().height;
const section1Height = section1.getBoundingClientRect().height;

let totalHeight = headerHeight + section1Height;

console.log(totalHeight);

const body = document.querySelector("body");
console.log(body);
body.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #ff99cc ${totalHeight}px)`;
body.style.backgroundSize = `100% ${totalHeight}`;
body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
body.style.backgroundSize = `100% ${totalHeight}px`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      header,
      footer,
      section {
        height: 30vh;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>header</header>
    <main style="max-width: 80vw; margin: 0 auto;">
      <section>section 1</section>
      <section>section 2</section>
      <section>section 3</section>
      <section>section 4</section>
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works! Good idea to use getBoundingClientRect in javascript.

Comment: While you were the fastest and your answer is on point, I have to accept @soimon's answer as it provides 3 alternatives. Thank you very much for your time, see you around.

Comment: @LouisCoulet : Dear Friend ! I am here to help... You may even downvote... That hardly matters. Just an advice though... The position:absolute; and header:pseudo solution is not a good one.. Avoid it... Rest is fine :) It can mess up things later in your code.. When you say need a navbar and submenus, then managing z-indexes is extra load :)